# Select empty values in dataframe, python

Tags: python, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe with empty values:
[image: dataframe]

I want to select non-empty values for field 'latitude'. I've tried

```
df[df['latitude'].notnull()]
```

and

```
df[df['latitude'] != '']
```

But these phrases select all values.

Comment: You are going to have to provide more details and a [mcve] for people to help

Comment: Please post either the output of `df.head()` or the first several lines of the file that the data frame is from instead of an image of the dataframe

Comment: Wild guess: "if df['latitude'] is not None: ..."